# Implementing a simple web browser with wxPython

Tags: browser, wxpython, pyjamas

I'm wondering if it is possible to implement a very simple web browser with wxPython, I know you can use `wx.html.LoadPage()` function but it does not work very well, I want a basic standalone/browser just like the following code ([image link](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/8140/1gjz.png)) written with Pyjamas with the `pyjd.setup()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you'll want to look at the HTML2_WebView widget. It's cross platform and should work for most websites. There is an example in the wxPython demo. Note that it's new in wxPython 2.9. You can read more about it in the documentation:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html

Or check out the following link for another example:

- [wxPython WebView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358998/wxpython-webview-example)