# capture server response in python

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm writing a helper for a webpage game.

I use a simple browser, as
[wxPython WebView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358998/wxpython-webview-example)

How can I capture the server response, for the request url is not stable(server ip may change), and also I don't want to send request myself(may lead to account banned).

I know there is a fiddlercore in .net. Is there any similar things in python?

Comment: You can capture the response from the module you are using to connect to the server; can you post the relevant piece of code?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly. I use wxpython to write a simple browser, link as above, and load the game webpage. The server is not mine, but the company who run the game. I checked the wxpython doc but didn't found related func.