# how to set a socks5 for wx.html2.WebView

Tags: python-3.x, webview, proxy, wxwidgets, socks

in this link there is a tutorial showing how to use wx webview:
[wxPython WebView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358998/wxpython-webview-example)

I need to know whether its possible to set socks5 with webview? thanks.

Comment: those are 2 different things. Did you have any problems with it?

Comment: its a browser and a browser can use proxy, I want use it with a proxy

Comment: did you already tried something?

Comment: I googled and found nothing, I searched in parameters by dir(different parameters) and found nothing useful.

Comment: what is you target system and which backend you will be using?

Comment: I want to use it in windows , using python 3 , but unfortunately I don't know backend meaning

Comment: Will you be using IE, FF or Chromium? Or Edge?

Comment: I prefer FireFox.I thought this is an independent browser not a com object like delphi and c# WebBrowser component.