# I'm having problems embedding an html file into wxpython

Tags: javascript, python, html, wxpython

I am creating a GUI element to visualize graphs generated using PyVis. PyVis outputs the graphs into an html file. You can open this file in a browser to see a fully interactive graph which looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSMPX.jpg).

The problem is that I'm now trying to embed this into a greater GUI design and when I try opening the html file in wxpython or tkinter (I have tried both), it ends up coming up as blank [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry9FM.jpg).

Here is the simple test code that I am using to produce this. I got this code from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358998/wxpython-webview-example):

```
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
   wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
   sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
   self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
   sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
   self.SetSizer(sizer)
   self.SetSize((700, 700))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = wx.App()
   dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
   dialog.browser.LoadURL("file:///C:/Users/GARcher/PycharmProjects/PROJECT/saved.html")
   dialog.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
```

The html file which I am trying to open is as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis-network.min.js"> </script>
<center>
<h1></h1>
</center>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.js"> </script>-->

<style type="text/css">

        #mynetwork {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

        

        

        
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id = "mynetwork"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // initialize global variables.
    var edges;
    var nodes;
    var network; 
    var container;
    var options, data;

    
    // This method is responsible for drawing the graph, returns the drawn network
    function drawGraph() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
        
        

        // parsing and collecting nodes and edges from the python
        nodes = new vis.DataSet([{"id": 1, "label": "192.168.0.121", "shape": "dot"}, {"id": 2, "label": "192.168.0.64", "shape": "dot"}, {"id": 3, "label": "192.168.0.101", "shape": "dot"}, {"id": 4, "label": "192.168.0.22", "shape": "dot"}, {"id": 5, "label": "192.168.0.69", "shape": "dot"}, {"id": 6, "label": "ROUTER", "shape": "dot"}]);
        edges = new vis.DataSet([{"from": 1, "to": 6}, {"from": 2, "to": 6}, {"from": 3, "to": 6}, {"from": 4, "to": 6}, {"from": 5, "to": 6}, {"from": 1, "to": 2}, {"from": 3, "to": 4}, {"from": 4, "to": 5}]);

        // adding nodes and edges to the graph
        data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};

        var options = {
    "configure": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "edges": {
        "color": {
            "inherit": true
        },
        "smooth": {
            "enabled": false,
            "type": "continuous"
        }
    },
    "interaction": {
        "dragNodes": true,
        "hideEdgesOnDrag": false,
        "hideNodesOnDrag": false
    },
    "physics": {
        "enabled": true,
        "stabilization": {
            "enabled": true,
            "fit": true,
            "iterations": 1000,
            "onlyDynamicEdges": false,
            "updateInterval": 50
        }
    }
};
        
        

        

        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
     
        


        

        return network;

    }

    drawGraph();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, my question is why is this not working in wxPython or tkinter and how can I resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [wx.html.HtmlWindow](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.html.HtmlWindow.html). This has a *LoadFile* method which is, I think, what you are looking for

```
import wx
import wx.html

GRAPH = "file:///C:/Users/GARcher/PycharmProjects/PROJECT/saved.html"


class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.browser = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetSize((700, 700))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
    dialog.browser.LoadFile(GRAPH)
    dialog.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sadly this still shows up as blank. I'm thinking of refactoring my entire GUI design into a web interface using something like Dash instead... I think I'll get better results doing that.